# Design dilemma on notifications Microservice using REST

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

I am creating a microservice in charge of executing all notifications (e.g. email, sms) that are triggered by other interfaces and microservices. This is to centralize all notification logic and processing. A notification action is triggered by calling its rest web service url.

Now this is my dilemma. Should I make a single url for each type of request or one url for all?

e.g.

OPTION1

```
@Path("{sourceId}/registationEmail")
@Path("{sourceId}/forgotPasswordEmail")
@Path("{sourceId}/productionTicketEmail")
@Path("{sourceId}/registationSms")
@Path("{sourceId}/forgotPasswordSms")
@Path("{sourceId}/productionTicketSms")
```

or

OPTION 2

```
@Path("{sourceId}/email")
@Path("{sourceId}/sms")
```

The problem here is we are using a @BeanParam as input, so every type of notification would have a different set of input values. That's the main issue we decide to go for option 2, or is there a way to get around that in the REST configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Richardson Maturity Model level 1](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level1), I'd say you really have at most 2 resources (aka option 2), and both could have a type property. Of course they're going to have a different set of input values, but all those email types should have the same properties, right (From, To, Subject, Body etc)? No point in having a separate endpoint if it's going to look and behave the same as 2 others.

Comment: The problem is the processing logic of constructing the email content is to be done by this Notifications web service, so we can't send the constructed message body to this service as input, only the required params to construct the message body

Comment: so what's the problem then? instead of having a body property, you'd have a couple of smaller (?), different ones, with different values for each email/sms type; as long as all emails require similar params (types/names, not actual values), this could be served through a single endpoint with a generic model

Comment: the problem is each email type requires a different set of input data. So, you can reuse the same BeanParam input.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for option 2:

```java
@Path("{sourceId}/email")
@Path("{sourceId}/sms")
```

It looks much better than the other option.

---

I don't know what your full URI looks like, but I would have something like `/sources/{sourceId}/email` or `/sources/{sourceId}/notification/email`.

And your request could be like:

```
POST /sources/{sourceId}/email HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "to": "mail@example.com",
  "subject": "Question 38602123",
  "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
}
```

---

You don't provide details on what your input looks like. No details on the dependencies you are using. Hence it's hard to guess and provide you with a definitive answer.

You mentioned [`@BeanParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html), so I assume you are using JAX-RS and one of its implementation such as Jersey. If you are using JSON or XML to represent your resources, it's very likely you are using Jackson.

So, to handle different inputs, you could use inheritance and Jackson polymorphic deserialization. There are a few annotations such as [`@JsonTypeInfo`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html) and [`@JsonSubTypes`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSubTypes.html) that will do the trick.

Comment: All email templates are to be managed by the notifications web service so sending the formatted message to the service cannot be done. Each email type also has a different set of input, so using a single @BeanParam class would end up having a lot of attributes to handle all the data input required for every time of notification

Comment: @DavoinShowerhandles Why don't you add an example to your question?